# Exporting CSV via Python with headers & date formatting

Tags: python, csv, date, datetime, cx-oracle

I'm looking to format the first column of my Export01.csv into dd/mm/yyyy. sadly the current format when I export it is dd/mm/yy mm:mm.

Could someone help me tweak my code to make the changes to the date during the import procedure if it's possible?

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle
import csv

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user','password','ORPM2') 
cursor = connection.cursor()


SQL="SELECT * FROM EXPORT01"
cursor.execute(SQL)

filename="C:\Projects\SQL_Export\Export01.csv"

with open(filename,"wb") as fout:
writer = csv.writer(fout)
writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row
writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())

fout.close()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

I've added a sample of the first two columns of data in Export01

```
WEEK_ENDING         ORDER_HEADLINE
12/02/2016 00:00    Headline
15/01/2016 00:00    Headline
15/01/2016 00:00    Headline
```

Comment: You don't need to close your file 'fout'  when you use "with" contextManager, also, you  need to respect the indentation level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle the fetchall a row at a time, you could then convert the first column entry as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import cx_Oracle
import csv


connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user','password', 'ORPM2') 
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQL="SELECT * FROM EXPORT01"
cursor.execute(SQL)
filename = r"C:\Projects\SQL_Export\Export01.csv"

with open(filename, "wb") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        cols = list(row)
        cols[0] = cols[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        writer.writerow(cols)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Also note, the `with` statement you are using will automatically close the file when you leave its scope. I would also recommend you prefix your file path with `r` to avoid Python trying to escape any of the backslashes in the path.

Comment: I'm getting the following error Martin........

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/803261400/desktop/Export2.py", line 25, in <module>
    row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%y %H:%M").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy over an import, you need to add `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Martin, thanks for your help. I'm getting the same errors........Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/803261400/desktop/Export2.py", line 23, in <module>
    row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%y %H:%M").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
TypeError: must be string, not datetime.datetime
>>>

Comment: Do you know which version of Python you are using?

Comment: I have assumed that the type of the first column is a string. Could you add `print type(row[0])` and tell me what it says.

Comment: <type 'datetime.datetime'> & the Export file show 12/02/2016  00:00:00

Comment: If it is already in datetime format then it just needs the strftime call. I have updated the scipt

Comment: Martin, now getting a new error. I've added the first two columns of the Export01 data as they include headers if that helps........TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Ok try now. It now first converts each row into a list so that the first column can be modified.